# Online formatter tool for the list output in debug log

Tags: list, debugging, formatting

do we have any tool just like JSON formatter, XML formatter to format the list output that is coming in debug log text. For example,

> [AccountOwner=null, Address=25 S. aka Ave. Duluth MN 802 US,
>   City=Duluth, Country=null, CustomerName=lisio Food, Inc.,
>   CustomerNameAlpha=lisio Food, Inc., CustomerNo=13332595, Email=null,
>   Fax=113-523-2356, GSSCnt=1, GSSRecomm=null, ManualOverride=false,
>   PostCode=55802, RecoPts=null, Region=US,
>   SAPCustMastSFDCId=a0To0000005lLwHEAU,
>   SAPSFDCKey=001o000000AmlI8AAJ_122595, SAPSFDCVal=(),
>   SFDCId=001o000000AmlI8AAJ, State=MN, StreetAddr=25 S. aka Ave.,
>   Telephone=118-123-4460, partnerfunc=SOLD]

Is there any online tool available to format this and display it in a readable format? It is very hard to look for a value when it is in this current format.

Experts advice please. Thanks

Comment: You could use standard online json beautifier. They show errors, but still look pretty neat. Try your string in this: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: Another option is to use `JSON.serialize()` when printing your log. This will force the output into valid JSON that can be formatted and consumed by other applications.

Comment: Thanks @D.S.. its a very good way to spit out in debug log. Great idea!

Answer (score 1):

I use to format this kind of text through Notepad++ software. like this.

Replace (press Ctrl + H) all commas by '\n\r', which gives me readable format.

[image: Notepad formatting]

You can download .exe or .zip version from [Notepad++ download link](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Comment: thanks @Santanu its good to hear that we have open source tools that do the job perfectly. Will give a try and let you know. Thanks